# TeamCity and Maven support

Tags: maven, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I noticed that TeamCity is not supporting Maven 3.3.x as a bundled plugin. 
So I placed Maven version (latest) under TeamCity master (TC/plugins/.tools) and it deployed the Maven to all build agents.

The problem is that there are missing functionality like missing maven-build-info.xml. that is generated during the build and create the "Maven build info" tab.

Is it a known issue? Is there any workaround?

Thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 4):

[Support for Maven 3.3.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-40521) was introduced in [TeamCity 9.0.4](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2015/04/teamcity-9-0-4-bugfix-is-released/), so make sure you are running that version or above.  Once you've done that, download and unzip Maven 3.3.X to a directory of your choosing.  Then in TeamCity, do the following:

1. Navigate to *Administration > Your Project > Your Build
   Configuration > Build Step: Maven > Edit*.
2. click *Show advanced options*.
3. Under *Maven selection:*, choose *<Custom>*.
4. Under *Custom path:* specify the path to where you unzipped Maven.
5. Click *Save*.

You should then be able to see the *Maven Build Info* tab when you next run your build for that project.